# Error accessing Azure Storage using DefaultAzureCredential

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have been using c# code to get blob items for the past few days, however, with no changes to the way the program gets the blob data, it stopped working. I run into the same error every time I run now:

**"EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured"**

Here is the code I am using to connect to Azure:

```
            Uri accountUri = new Uri(mystorageurl);
            BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClient(accountUri, new DefaultAzureCredential(true));
            BlobContainerClient container = client.GetBlobContainerClient(blobname);
            BlobClient bundle = container.GetBlobClient(itemname);
```

What I've been confused by is that if I run this same code in a separate vs solution, I get no error getting the files from Azure. I've also tried sending the same solution that's getting the error to another person and they were able to run it without issue. I know it isn't an issue with environment variables, since it used to work up until now and they haven't been modified in any way.

This unresolved issue on github is most similar to what I've encountered:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/16079

Comment: Have you validated the [`Environment Variables`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#environment-variables)? Is it correct?

Comment: @PamelaPeng Yes, initially I never created the variables and the program worked just fine. After the first few crashes though I added them in with the correct values and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine when you **never** set Environment variables, it means that you didn't use `EnvironmentCredential`. The `DefaultAzureCredential` will attempt to authenticate via the following mechanisms in order, and Environment is the first one.

[image]

If you just use Environment to authenticate, it's better to use **EnvironmentCredential** instead of **DefaultAzureCredential**. And it's necessary to set the following variables.

`AZURE_CLIENT_ID`: id of an Azure Active Directory application

`AZURE_TENANT_ID`: id of the application's Azure Active Directory tenant

`AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`: one of the application's client secrets